# Connected components of the complement of a connected component

Tags: general-topology

Sorry for the "crazy" title, but that's what it is...

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Let $E$ be a subset of $X$.

Let $F$ be a connected component of $E$.

Is the following true? Why?

> For every connected component $C$ of $X \setminus F$, there exists a connected component $D$ of $X \setminus E$ such that $D \subseteq C$.

In case there is a counterexample, can we restrict the hypotheses on $X$ and $E$ to make it work? (For example, compactness of $E$ or $X = \mathbb R^2$.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised to match the revised question:**

The answer to the revised question is *yes*. Let $C$ be a component of $X\setminus F$. There must be a component $D$ of $X\setminus E$ such that $D\cap C\ne\varnothing$. If $D\nsubseteq C$, then $C\cup D$ is a connected subset of $X\setminus F$ properly containing the component $C$, which is impossible. Thus, $D\subseteq C$.

Comment: I meant $D \subseteq C$ instead of $C \subseteq D$ in the question, which changes everything. Sorry for making you lose your time.